# editing the legend on geom_text()

Tags: r, ggplot2

i never have trouble editing the legend with ggplot, but with geom_text I seem to be having some trouble.

`i <- ggplot(threedusg, aes(x=DxRAPM, y=X3PAr, label=threedusg$Player))
i + geom_text(aes(size=threedusg$CS3,hjust=0,vjust=0)) + scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,6))`

Here is what my legend looks [image: like]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/44udh.jpg

The size of the text comes from data with percentages.  I would prefer to have the text in the legend read as actual percentages.  For instance it says .30 instead of 30%.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `scales` library (which you will need to explicitly load), you can use the `percent` labeller. (Note you shouldn't be referencing the columns of a data set using `$` within a ggplot call.

```
library(scales)

ggplot(threedusg, aes(x = DxRAPM, y = X3PAr, label = Player)) +
  geom_text(aes(size = CS3), hjust = 0, vjust = 0) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,6)) +
  scale_size(label = percent)
```

On a reproducible example

```
foo <- data.frame(x=1:5,y=1:5,player=letters[1:5],rate = c(0.2,0.5,0.7,0.1,0.8))
ggplot(foo, aes(x=x,y=y,label=player)) + 
  geom_text(aes(size=rate)) + 
  scale_size(label = percent)
```

[image]